# How to click an Android App element in Tricentis Tosca by explcitly specifying its XPath?

Tags: xpath, dynamic, tosca

Is it possible to click and element in an Android application using Tricentis Tosca by specifying the actual XPath of the element? What module can be used?

TIA!

I tried modifying the Resource ID and Name of an existing scanned element to have a dynamic xpath by using xbuffer but error occurs when executed.

Comment: Is this an HTML5 application? Then, XBrowser might be helpful https://documentation.tricentis.com/tosca/1310/en/content/engines_3.0/xbrowser/xbrowser_controls.htm